# tsql conditional maths equation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I need to perform some summations during a select query however depending on 2 values i will need to perform a different equation.  hopefully an example will demonstrate

basically i need to perform the following summations

```
if x > y then (x - y + z) or
if x < y then (x - x + z) basically i am setting this to 0.
```

So far i thought that i could use 2 tables to dump the x > y values and the x < y values and then perform the relevant equations.

any ideas

Comment: looks like you have 3 values here ... can you elaborate on what you require with the tables you have and the result that you need ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a case expression.

```
select case 
         when x > y then x - y + z
         when x < y then x - x + z
         else 0 -- x = y
       end  
from YourTable
```

Comment: Technically, it's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes of course. Thanks. I **am** struggling a bit with English but is almost fluent in T-SQL :).